# Get the garbage values from mysql database correctly in hindi

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have a database that is having values stored in the form "à¤–à¥‡à¤²"( for खेल). It is getting displayed correctly on previous website by just fetching the data from the database.However when i dumped that database and try to fetch using queries in codeignitor, it displays the raw value i.e à¤–à¥‡à¤² instead of खेल.
I have set charset to utf-8 in header as well as in database.php file in codeigniter. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously data was stored in latin-1 format and whwn i dumped that in my database which was in unicode format the values come in the form of "à¤–à¥‡à¤²"( for खेल), so i fired following query in the database

> convert(cast(convert(category using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)

for converting data in category column back to appropriate format i.e खेल.

Comment: Just to add on the correct syntax for easier reference:
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET 
    COLUMN =convert(cast(convert(COLUMN using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)
WHERE 1

Answer (score 0):

I tried this I'm also not getting the output.I tried setting db collation to utf8_unicode_ci also.But it is not working.

What I usually does is store the data as varchar with collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci so we could store the data in Hindi itself (ie खेल instead of à¤–à¥‡à¤²) .This helps me in reading and debuging easily in sql itself